# jQuery Mobile: Partial page view

Tags: jquery-mobile

jQuery Mobile is excellent when it comes to managing pages and page transitions, but does anyone know of a good way to produce partial page views (preferably in response to a swipe event)? For example, the user performs a right swipe to reveal a hidden menu similar to the Facebook app.

Comment: I think you are referring to a slide in panel, which I suspect is accomplished with CSS in most cases. Using a negative margin for a div, you could slide it in by returning its margin to 0 and increasing the Page margin by the same amount. You could also float it and have it cover the current page. If that's what you're looking for, I can see if I can find an example for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile v1.3 Side Pannels. The beta should be out soon (jan?).

http://jquerymobile.com/branches/slide-panel-refactor/docs/panels/index.html

Comment: I love you. How did you find this? So, is there a way I can use this now?

Comment: Not an expert with git but it is a branch. Other functionality may or may not be there. Not likely something you can use today but hopefully it will be out in an official beta soon. I follow the jquery updates (http://jquery.org/updates/) and it is in there on the Dec 20th meeting.

Comment: I may have originally seen it as a related twitter post by one of the jqm core team members. I also read some place that there are some performance issues with the "push" mode that may be dropped. You will still get the Overlay and Reveal methods.

Comment: David, Looks like activity on this is heating up. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/commits/

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a working plugin recreation of facebook slide menu created for jQuery Mobile.

You can find it here: https://github.com/tegansnyder/JQuery-Mobile-Slide-Menu

Here's an example: http://www.tegdesign.com/tegansnyder-JQuery-Mobile-Slide-Menu/

It works with swipe events, or it can be triggered by click event.

You can use this plugin/example to create your partial view component.